# One Fluorescent Fitting not working in parallel

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, fluorescent, ballast

I know it's not the bulb or the ballast (it's a starterless ballast), I've swapped bulbs to a different unit in same circuit, the bulb works in both of them but both don't work at the same time, I've even tried a different bulb in the same connections, only one works at once and not always the same one, no clue here, any ideas?

Comment: Often the carriers that the end of the bulbs fit in are faulty. Either the small tabs get bent or a wire comes loose.  Check those.

Comment: Don't think it's that as both of the individual units work, just not at the same time

Comment: Are these the standard 4 foot fluorescent fixtures?  If so, just change out the fixture.  Or better change to the new LED fixtures.

Comment: Six foot fittings, might be an option, just more hassle if it's not needed